# Xcode 8, cannot pair watch simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, apple-watch, xcode8

I'm running Xcode 8 beta 5.  My app has a watch extension.  I cannot pair the iPhone simulator with the watch simulator.  I've followed the instructions for pairing (Xcode, Window, Devices) but there are no watch simulators listed there, nor are any listed when I select any of the iPhone simulators.  I've tried variations of Add Simulator, but I only get more iPhone simulators -- I never see a watch simulator or a pairing there.  The watch simulator exists -- I can launch the simulator, but it isn't paired.  I've tried deleting Xcode and re-installing.  Same issue with beta 4.

How do I get the watch simulator to appear when I select an iPhone simulator in Device?

**UPDATE:** To be clear, these are Apple's instructions for "Pairing Apple Watch Simulators to iPhone Simulators" (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/PairingWatchestoiPhoneSimulators/PairingWatchestoiPhoneSimulators.html)

> 1. In the Devices window under Simulators, select an iPhone 5 and later simulator.
> 2. Under the Paired Watches table, click the Add button (+).

I never see the "Paired Watches table" so there's no Add button.

I do see that in Xcode 7, like this:
[image: Paired Watched table (Xcode 7)]
 **UPDATE 2:**
In Xcode 8 beta 6, the Paired Watches table appears in the Devices window, but the pairing still fails with a "Simulator Not Paired" dialog.

Comment: What's the output of 'xcrun simctl list'?  Do you see your pairs listed there?  Try pairing your devices with 'xcrun simctl pair ...'

Comment: There's a mass of output, but no pairings.  And if I have the Xcode 8 sims running, the xcrun command crashes.  How do I get it to use the Xcode 8 versions, and how do I specify the sims to pair?

Comment: Can you send me the crash log (pastebin, etc)? -- You can create a pair with the 'pair' subcommand.  Eg: 'xcrun simctl pair <UDID> <UDID>'

Comment: To use the Xcode 8 version, make sure you have Xcode 8 selected with 'xcode-select'  Eg:  'sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app'

Comment: Now using Xcode 8 Beta 6 which shows the Paired Watches tables, I get "<UDID> (active, disconnected)"  "Watch: Apple Watch - 42mm (<UDID>) (Shutdown)"  "Phone: iPhone SE (<UDID>) (Booted)"  which appears to match the Devices window (so I have a pairing), but I still see the "Simulator Not Paired" dialog in the SE simulator when I launch the Watch app.  I've tried creating a new iPhone simulator in Devices and pairing that, but no joy.

Comment: For pairing to complete, both the watch and phone simulators need to boot (at the same time).

Comment: I see no way to do that.  They're separate apps, and they load and run at very different rates.  I can launch one before the other, but the order makes no difference.

Comment: Launch Simulator.app to boot the phone.  Launch Simulator (Watch).app to boot the watch.  Choose the devices you want from the 'Hardware -> Device' menus in the respective apps.

Comment: Jeremy: I was able to successfully pair the watch, but I had to create a new watch simulator with a unique name, pair that in Xcode Devices, then select it in the watch's Hardware, Device menu.  The watch's Hardware, Device list was full of many "Apple Watch - 42mm" (the default pairings) so I thought it was correct.  Other than your comment here, there's no mention of having to match the devices, and find the EXACT device in the long list of many with the same name -- it should be more automatic.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Pairs are automatically created for you.  To complete the pairing, you just need to have both devices booted at the same time (so they can sync).  That's usually done automatically for you the first time you Build & Run a watchOS Application.

Comment: Noting was automatic for me in beta 5 -- there were no pairings and I couldn't create one.  In beta 6, there were default pairings, but the proper one was not selected in the watch Devices menu where there were (and still are) many *identically-named* simulators in the list.  Until I created a simulator with a unique name, I didn't realize I could have selected one after the other to eventually find the proper pair.  The experience was not automatic nor smooth.  However, your comments were helpful and encouraging in my ultimately getting it working.  Thank you.

Comment: @Jeff thank you, recreating the simulator was the only way to fix it on my build, was using xcode 8 (GM seed) - could be the accepted answer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found two ways to deal with the multiple, identically-named simulators:

1. Xcode Devices window: Create a new watch simulator for a particular iPhone device and give it a unique name (e.g., "test3").  When you launch the watch simulator, select that simulator in the watch's Hardware, Device menu.

[image: Xcode Device's window]￼￼

2. Xcode: Select and Run the iPhone app in Xcode's Active Scheme dropdown menu, then select and Run the WatchKit App in the Active Scheme, too.  Each of those actions will launch the correctly-paired simulators, even if the names are ambiguous.

￼[image: Xcode Active Scheme menu (iPhone app)]
￼
[image: Xcode Active Scheme window (WatchKit App)]

Comment: great answer..i was finally able to lauch my watch app in simulator after using this solution..