# Xcode 9.4 Apple Watch Simulator Will Not Pair with iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, watchkit, apple-watch

I cannot get an Apple Watch to pair with an iPhone in the simulator even when adding a new device and pairing a watch according to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892959/xcode-8-cannot-pair-watch-simulator) instructions.  I can see from the red disconnected icon at the top of the watch that it's not paired even though Xcode thinks it is? When I tap on the Apple Watch App on the iPhone it says device not paired and to do it in Xcode.

Nothing I've tried has been able to fix including a full reinstall of Xcode.  I've also tried deleting derived data as well as everything inside ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/watchOS DeviceSupport.

I also installed the Xcode 10.3 beta yesterday, could this have something to do with it?

Comment: I do have the same issue. Xcode also freezes (beachball) when I try to stop the process

Comment: @benrudhart please post here if you are able to figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:  I am still not sure what caused the problem but installing Xcode Beta 10.4 fixed this issue for beta version's simulator as well as Xcode 9's simulator.

Comment: I was having the exact same problem w/ Xcode 9.4.1 and Xcode 10.0 beta 3 installed. Upgrading to beta 6 fixed the problem 